# How to create a custom HAL in aosp and access its methods from Android Application?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-source, hal

So after creating a custom hal how can we access its method through android application

Trying this out , will post if it works

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. kindly try to explain the question clearly with clarity on the main part itself. Please post your research on the same with the script/code/images along with the difficulty you face. To get a clear idea of how to ask a question. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Create a jni layer and through the jni layer you can access the HAL methods.